# Jquery add clasc to higher id dynamic

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add class to ids dynamic. The problem is that I need to add a class to current and next ids. I have this code:

```
if ($('#id_0').hasClass('active')){
 $('#id_0').removeClass("active");
 $('#id_1').addClass("active");
 }
 else if ($('#id_1').hasClass('active')){
 $('#id_1').removeClass("active");
 $('#id_2').addClass("active");
 }
```

etc..

So I try to write it dynamic like this:

```
$('.my-class').each(function(i,e) {
    if ($('#id_' + (i)).hasClass('active')){
    $('.#id_' + (i)).removeClass("active"); 
    $('#id_' + (i+1)).addClass("active"); 
    }
```

The problem is that this line not working

```
$('#id_' + (i+1)).addClass("active");
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: where `i` is defined?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for responding. I using this code to generate dynamic ids:

Comment: $('#slides-titles-cont li.title-slider').each(function(i, e){
        $(this).append('<li class="title-slider"></li>').attr("id", "id_" + i)
});

Comment: can you paste the error you getting?

Comment: The error is that class is not added to the next id. It is removed from current id, but not added to the next. The first 2 lines are ok, but how I can add a class to the next id?

Comment: $('.#id_' + (i)) there is a dot before # is this a bad typo??

Comment: Please share the relevant html code in your question

Comment: This is typo error here where I past it $('.#id_' + (i)) . Should be $('#id_' + (i))

Comment: The original code $('.title-slider').each(function(i,e) {
  if ($('.title-slider#id_' + (i)).hasClass('active')){
  $('.title-slider#id_' + (i)).removeClass("active"); 
  $('.title-slider#id_' + (i+1)).addClass("active"); 
  }
  });

Answer (score 0):

The code that is working, but is not dynamic is:

```
if ($('.title-slider#id_0').hasClass('active')){
 $('.title-slider#id_0').removeClass("active");
 $('.title-slider#id_1').addClass("active");
 }
 else if ($('.title-slider#id_1').hasClass('active')){
 $('.title-slider#id_1').removeClass("active");
 $('.title-slider#id_2').addClass("active");
 }
 else if ($('.title-slider#id_2').hasClass('active')){
 $('.title-slider#id_2').removeClass("active");
 $('.title-slider#id_3').addClass("active");
 }
  else if ($('.title-slider#id_3').hasClass('active')){
 $('.title-slider#id_3').removeClass("active");
 $('.title-slider#id_4').addClass("active");
 }
  else if ($('.title-slider#id_4').hasClass('active')){
 $('.title-slider#id_4').removeClass("active");
 $('.title-slider#id_5').addClass("active");
 }
  else if ($('.title-slider#id_5').hasClass('active')){
 $('.title-slider#id_5').removeClass("active");
 $('.title-slider#id_6').addClass("active");
 }
  else if ($('.title-slider#id_6').hasClass('active')){
 $('.title-slider#id_6').removeClass("active");
 $('.title-slider#id_7').addClass("active");
 }
```

So I try to writing it like this:

```
$('.title-slider').each(function(i,e) {
    if ($('.title-slider#id_' + (i)).hasClass('active')){
    $('.title-slider#id_' + (i)).removeClass("active"); 
    $('.title-slider#id_' + (i+1)).addClass("active"); 
    }
 });
```

The last line is not working. Only first two lines are ok.

Comment: I found the solution. It is easy: $('.title-slider.active').removeClass(function(){
      $(this).next().addClass('active');
      return 'active';

Answer (score 0):

The solution for thi is:

```
$('.title-slider.active').removeClass(function(){
  $(this).next().addClass('active');
  return 'active';
```